# Checking values of hash before show in jbuider , Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have a jbuilder to show my object.

Thats how it looks (part of it)

```
o = @property_object

json.features o.property_object_feature_pack, :pool, :garage, terrace
```

and this showing me next:

```
{
 features: {
  pool: {
   params: null,
   present: "false"
   },
  garage_parking: {
   params: null,
   present: "false"
   },
  terrace_balcony: {
   params: null,
   present: "true"
   }
 }
}
```

Question is that I don't want to show in output features with **present: "false"** . To solve this I write next code

```
json.features o.property_object_feature_pack, :pool if o.property_object_feature_pack.pool['present'] === "true"
json.features o.property_object_feature_pack, :garage_parking if o.property_object_feature_pack.garage_parking['present'] === "true"
json.features o.property_object_feature_pack, :terrace_balcony if o.property_object_feature_pack.terrace_balcony['present'] === "true"
```

And it works - but looks awful. How it can be refactored?

Next problem that it can be new features to be added in ActiveRecord in future, and I want to know  can we iterate over  o.property_object_feature_pack without setting names ? (:pool, :garage_parking etc.. )

**ps.** raw o.property_object_feature_pack

```
features: {
 id: 820,
 property_object_id: 56879,
 created_at: "2015-04-27T18:25:25.712Z",
 updated_at: "2015-04-27T18:25:25.712Z",
 pool: {
  params: null,
  present: "false"
 },
 garage_parking: {
  params: null,
  present: "false"
 },
 terrace_balcony: {
  params: null,
  present: "true"
 },
 av_apartments: {
  params: null,
  present: "false"
 }
}
```

**Updated**

Inspired by #mudasobwa I had create a little helper method that solves my question

```
def features_list
    @property_object.property_object_feature_pack.as_json.select! do |_, v|
      v.is_a?(Hash) && v['present'] == 'true'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue about what `jbuilder` is, but I would suggest to convert json into plain ruby hash, do whatever you want and convert it back into json:

```
require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse what_you_got_from_builder
hash[:features].select! do |_, v| 
  !v.is_a?(Hash) || v[:present] == 'true' 
end
hash.to_json
```

Comment: Not exactly answer, but you push me to the right way. In the end I had create a helper that do what I need. 

`def features_list
    @property_object.property_object_feature_pack.as_json.select! do |_, v|
      v.is_a?(Hash) && v['present'] == 'true'
    end
  end`